# Pointwise and uniform convergence of $f_n(x)=\sqrt[n]{nx^2+1}$

Tags: solution-verification, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function

Study the pointwise and uniform convergence of $f_n(x)=\sqrt[n]{nx^2+1}$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

My attempt: let $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ fixed, it is
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{nx^2_0+1}=1$$
So $f_n$ converges pointwise to $f(x)=1$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

For the study of the uniform convergence, I have to evaluate
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}}|\sqrt[n]{nx^2+1}-1|$$
The $n$-th root is an increasing function, so since $nx^2+1 \geq 1$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ it is $\sqrt[n]{nx^2+1}-1 \geq 0$ and so $|\sqrt[n]{nx^2+1}-1|=(\sqrt[n]{nx^2+1}-1)$; moreover, it is
$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}(\sqrt[n]{nx^2+1}-1)=\frac{2x}{n}(nx^2+1)^{\frac{1-n}{n}} \geq 0 \iff x \geq 0$$
So the function $f_n-f$ is increasing function of $x$ and it is an unbounded function of $x$, since
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} (f_n(x)-f(x)) = \lim_{x \to -\infty} (f_n(x)-f(x)) =\infty$$
So it is
$$\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}}(\sqrt[n]{nx^2+1}-1)=\infty$$
So $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} |\sqrt[n]{nx^2+1}-1|=\infty$, this means that the $f_n$ doesn't converge uniformly to $f(x)=1$ in $\mathbb{R}$.
However, given $a>0$ and considered the interval $[-a,a]$, by the same argument of monotonicity it is
$$\sup_{x \in [-a,a]} |\sqrt[n]{nx^2+1}-1|=\sqrt[n]{na^2+1}-1 \to 0 \ \text{as} \ n \to \infty$$
So $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f(x)=1$ in every compact subset $[-a,a]$ of $\mathbb{R}$.

My questions are the following:

1. When I study the positivity of the derivative, I omit the term $(nx^2+1)^{\frac{1-n}{n}}$ because I see it as an exponential and so I conclude it is always positive. I have in general problems with the $n$-th power and $n$-th roots, is this correct?
2. When I study the uniform converge in $\mathbb{R}$ I have to take the limit of a supremum which is already $\infty$; this never happened in my previous study, so I'm unsure about this step. It has some sense to take the limit of something that is already $\infty$?
3. The fact that the convergence is uniform in every compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$ but it can't be extended in $\mathbb{R}$ is because when we introduce $a>0$ for defining the interval $[-a,a]$ we are fixing $a$ and so we can conclude with the estimation on the supremum while the elements of $\mathbb{R}$ are considered elements that vary without a fixed bound (unlike $a$) and this makes the difference for the uniform convergence? Or is there a deeper reason why the uniform convergence fails in $\mathbb{R}$ but holds in every compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$?

Thank you.

Comment: Your arguments are essentially correct but the proof needs to be made clearer.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: Thank you, can you point out specifically where I can improve my arguments? You mean, for example, in my question 3 (which I agree with you, it was just an intuitive idea that I haven't developed yet) or in the general arguments I've written in the solution of the exercise?

Answer (score 1):

When you look at the limit for fixed $x_0$, why aren't you justifying the limit you write? I don't think it's dead obvious that limit is $1$.

After that, when you try to find the supremum of $|\sqrt[n]{nx^2 +1} - 1|$ for $x \in R$, what is your first impression about how big you can make this expression, if you're allowed to choose $x$ any way you like?

Comment: Yes I've omitted it because it is a "calculus 1" limit; however I'll write here: since it is $\sqrt[n]{nx_0^2+1}=\exp \left(\frac{1}{n} \log (nx_0^2+1)\right)$, the exponent tends to $0$ as $n\to\infty$ and hence the limit is $1$.
For your second question: the first impression is that I can make the expression big as I want, and I've proved it too (if I haven't made some mistakes). What do you wanted me to observe with this question? Thank you!

Comment: Hi Gwyn. For the second question, I'm not sure why you don't just say that as $x \to +\infty$, we have $nx^2 + 1 \to +\infty$, hence also $\sqrt[n]{nx^2 + 1} - 1 \to +\infty$. There's no need to differentiate as you do. I think you are doing this to prove that the function $f_n - f$ is increasing, but: (1) there is no need to know that it is increasing if the question is uniform convergence on R; (2) even if you wanted to know it was increasing, this would be obvious without differentiation, as...

Comment: it is the composite of the increasing functions $x \mapsto nx^2 + 1, x \mapsto \sqrt[n]{x}, x \mapsto x-1$.

Comment: You are right, since it is positively unbounded I can deduce instantly that the supremum in $\mathbb{R}$ is $\infty$ without noticing that it is increasing. I overdone, thank you for making me noticing it. And thanks for the observation on the composition of increasing functions as well!

Comment: Just to point something out, when I say it's a composite of increasing functions, that's perhaps a sophisticated way of expressing the argument. I don't want to make it sound too complicated. The way I really think about it mentally is this: "As $x$ increases (for $x > 0$), so does $nx^2 + 1$, hence so too do $\sqrt[n]{nx^2 + 1}$ and $\sqrt[n]{nx^2 + 1} - 1$," and in fact it would be fine to write the argument that way.

Answer (score 0):

to deduce the non-convergence in $\mathbb{R}$, which seems to take
$$ x_n = \sqrt {\frac {n^n-1}{n}}$$
(deducted from imposing $nx^2+1 = n^n $). In this case
$$
f_n(x_n)-1 = n-1
$$
and
$$ \sup (f_n(x)-1) \geq f_n(x_n)=n-1 $$
and the limit:
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \sup (f_n(x)-1) \geq 
\lim_{n \to \infty} (n-1) = \infty \neq 0
$$
implies non-convergence in $\mathbb{R}$.